# Перенос количества элементов интервала в список на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, выборка

Подскажите, как перенести количество элементов (подчёркнутые красным) в отдельный список.
Пробовал с помощью `append`, но ничего не вышло. Выводится только последний элемент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[sample1.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2e1Q/4bhQxGJaY)
Пример кода:

```
import csv
import math

Sample=[]
with open("sample1.csv", encoding="ANSI") as V:
    SR=csv.reader(V, delimiter=';')
    for row in SR:
        Sample.append(float(row[0]))
print(sorted(Sample))

aggregate=Sample

# Объём выборки
N=len(aggregate)
print("Объём выборки (N): ", N)

# Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов группировки
m=1+(math.log10(N)/math.log10(2))
print("Рекомендуемое кол-во интервалов для всей выборки (m): ", "%.0f" % m)

# Наибольшее и наименьшее значение выборки
min_volue=min(aggregate)
max_volue=max(aggregate)
print("Наименьшее значение выборки (min volue): ", "%.0f" %  min_volue)
print("Наибольшее значение выборки (max volue): ", "%.0f" %  max_volue)

botton_line=int(input("Введите нижнею границу: "))
top_line=int(input("Введите верхнею границу: "))

# Ввод кол-во интервалов группировки
kol_interval=int(input("Введите кол-во интервалов (kol_interval): "))

# Величина интервала
delta=((top_line-botton_line)/kol_interval)
print("Величина интервала (delta): ", "%.0f" % delta, "\n")

# Список границ интервалов
for x in range(kol_interval):
    c0=botton_line+delta*x
    c1=botton_line+delta*(x+1)
    print(f"{x+1}-й интервал имеет границы от", "%.0f" % c0, "до ", "%.0f" % c1)
    # Расчёт количества элементов в каждом интервале
    counter=0
    for i in aggregate:
        if c0<=i<c1:
            counter+=1
    print("Количество элементов: ", counter, "\n")

# Вывод элементов в список
elements=[]
elements.append(counter)
print("Элементы: ", elements)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так надо внутрь цикла внести append:

```
# Список границ интервалов
# Вывод элементов в список
elements=[]
for x in range(kol_interval):
    c0=botton_line+delta*x
    c1=botton_line+delta*(x+1)
    print(f"{x+1}-й интервал имеет границы от", "%.0f" % c0, "до ", "%.0f" % c1)
    # Расчёт количества элементов в каждом интервале
    counter=0
    for i in aggregate:
        if c0<=i<c1:
            counter+=1
    print("Количество элементов: ", counter, "\n")
    elements.append(counter)

print("Элементы: ", elements)
```

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то не додумался сразу